# Change Inbox-icons in Outlook at runtime

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

I have a problem in my Outlook Addin. My AddIn processes the incoming mails and validates different headers etc. I want to check if a specific headers is set and then change the Icon of this mail in my inbox folder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can either

1. change the icon to a couple dozen or so predefined icons used by Outlook itself (e.g. when it shows that a message was replied to/forwarded) by modifying the `PR_ICON_INDEX MAPI` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003`) using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`. You can play with that property and its different values in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - select a message with a replied/forwarded icon, click IMessage button, double click on the `PR_ICON_INDEX` MAPI property to modify it.
2. Install your own custom form. You can specify the message class that the form handles and your custom icon. If you change the message class of a message, Outlook will show your custom icon.

Comment: Is option 2 valid to show a custom icon in a new column in the messages grid from the explorer? What is a custom form and how to implement it? Do you have any code snippet?

Comment: No, the form's icon will only show instead of the standard Outlook icon. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/outlook-forms/create-an-outlook-form

Answer (score 0):

No, custom icons can be bu used with custom forms only. So, you need to publish a custom form to get the icon changed.

But you are free to handle the incoming emails. For example, you may handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox.

This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem, MeetingItem, or SharingItem. The EntryIDsCollection string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Note that this behavior has changed from earlier versions of the event when the EntryIDCollection contained a list of comma-delimited Entry IDs of all the items received in the Inbox since the last time the event was fired.

The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the NameSpace.GetItemFromID method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously.

You can use the [PropertyAccessor.GetProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868350(v=office.15).aspx) method to get the PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS property value:

```
 Sub DemoPropertyAccessorGetProperty() 
  Dim PropName, Header As String 
  Dim oMail As Object 
  Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
  'Get first item in the inbox 
  Set oMail = _ 
  Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items(1) 
  'PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS 
  PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E" 
  'Obtain an instance of PropertyAccessor class 
  Set oPA = oMail.PropertyAccessor 
  'Call GetProperty 
  Header = oPA.GetProperty(PropName) 
  Debug.Print (Header) 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any way to inherit an original form when us FormRegion way ? I would like custom icon, but can't really go for redesigning the whole mail form from scratch (especially since it gets updated over time)