# Change Outlook Inbox-icons envelope icons

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin

following this link - [change outlook MailItem icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTY74.png)

I managed to change my inbox icons.

Here's what I did step by step.
1) Created a custom message class for new mail that arrives from the Internet
The class is IPM.Note.Internet

```
Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace;
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox;
Outlook.Items items;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

        items = inbox.Items;

        items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
    }

    void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
    { 
        Outlook.MailItem mailitem = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
        String EmailHeader = mailitem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E");
        if (Item != null && EmailHeader.Contains("Look for a string in the headers here that we set for incomming mail") == true)
        {
            if (mailitem.MessageClass == "IPM.Note")
            {
                mailitem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note.Internet";
                mailitem.Save();
            }
        }
    }
```

2) Created a replacement Outlook Form Region matching the MessageClass. In this case I used IPM.Note.Internet

3) Assign the Icons in the Properties Pane of the Form Region Designer. 
[image]

4) Debugged project and the next message that arrived from the internet was stamped with my custom icons after the message class was updated.

My issue now is that I can't preview or open the messages where I changed the message class. Similar to this post that's unanswered  - [Change Inbox-icons in Outlook at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477432/change-inbox-icons-in-outlook-at-runtime)

I think the issue is that my replacement Outlook Form Region is blank so the message is not able to be previewed.

If this is true than here's my question. What is the best way to export the standard IPM.Note message class template into visual Studio. I thing I need to overwrite my IPM.Note.Internet Outlook Form Region design.

There is an option when creating an Outlook Form Region-
[image]

To import an ".OFS" file. I was attempting to figure out how to export the file from the Outlook 2010 Client (Developer Tools) but I can't find a way to save the templates to that specific format. I can save to OFT (office template) but not .OFS

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What exactly does the preview pane show?

Comment: Nothing, it's just blank. If I rename the message class, for one message,  back to IPM.Note from IPM.Note.Internet I can preview the message

Answer (score 1):

Rather then adding a form region and changing the message class I just ended up adding the PR_ICON_INDEX property and setting it's value. As outlined here in option #2 by Dmitry [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477432/change-inbox-icons-in-outlook-at-runtime)

There are many icons to choose from here. I couldn't locate a list with the integer values so I just entered random numbers for the PR_ICON_INDEX property in Outlook Spy changing the value till located the icon I wanted. There are many icons to choose from. Many from the 600-700 and 1000 and up range.

Here's the line I used to set the PR_ICON_INDEX property on the message-

```
mailitem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003", 4); // change the 4 to something like 600,601...etc to experiment
```

Comment: This doesn't allow for custom icons though

Comment: Correct, but there are hundreds of icons to choose from.

Comment: Also, I noticed that, say you set an icon on the mail, then you happen to reply to the mail. The icon gets changed from whatever you set before to the "reply icon" (circled arrow to the left), so icon doesn't last long since there are icons for many mail stats besides the replied state one

Comment: The caveat of using PR_ICON_INDEX is that it is being changed by Outlook itself on reply, forward, etc. messages so you need to constantly monitor it and handle when it happens so you can replace it again with the one you desire.